# how to mock viewmodel that inject using dagger hilt for android testing

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, dagger-hilt

I use `dagger hilt` in my project. I want to write `UI test` for some fragments. I need to mock the `viewModel` in the test class and associate it to the fragment under the test.. I read `dagger hilt` document but I didn't find any solution.

```
   class HomeViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val repository: MainRepository,
    prefManager: PrefManager,
    private val firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
 /////
}

    @AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
/////
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to test your fragment with mock data, you don't have to mock the view model; instead, you can provide mock repository implementation in a dagger module:

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = SingletonComponent::class,
    replaces = ProdRepositoryModule::class
)
interface FakeRepositoryModule {
  @Binds fun bind(impl: FakeRepository): MainRepository
}
```

When running UI tests, this will replace all the bindings provided in the `ProdRepositoryModule` module with the bindings provided in the `FakeRepositoryModule` module. Check out the [Hilt Testing](https://dagger.dev/hilt/testing) documentation for further assistance.